# Getting all agent status in amazon connect instance

Tags: amazon-connect

I am trying to build a supervisor kind of screen in Amazon connect mirroring the Finesse Supervisor desktop. So I am looking for a way to get the all available agent State & Queue Status in Amazon connect through any API.

Currently I am able to get single connected agent details through [**Streams API**](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams). But for this method I can not provide the agent ID or name to get the state of all agents.

Can anyone help me with any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at Amazon Connect Agent Event Streams.

I have included the link to the API for Agent Events.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/agent-event-streams.html

Here is a link to an Amazon provided solution Wallboard.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/building-a-serverless-contact-center-wallboard-for-amazon-connect/

I would not build the UI via python, i would use something like React, Vue or Angular.  This is what we have done to provide the data for Managers and Wallboards.